# MediaWiki: How to Update.php maintenance script on wiki family?

Tags: php, database, upgrade, mediawiki, wiki

I am running a MediaWiki wiki-family, with shared codebase and shared database. I recently successfully upgraded to `1.25.3`.

My wiki has 4 prefixes ATM, like so:

```
en_
de_
es_
shared_
```

I try to run my update.php script like so:

```
php update.php --wiki myWikiName-de_ --doshared
php update.php --wiki myWikiName-en_ --doshared
php update.php --wiki myWikiName-es_ --doshared
```

on my server. This should in theory work. Sadly it ALWAYS uses the `myWikiName-en_` and ignores my input..

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/myWiki/wiki/LocalSettings.php on line 176
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in <b>/var/www/myWiki/wiki/LocalSettings.php</b> on line <b>176</b><br />
MediaWiki 1.25.3 Updater

Your composer.lock file is up to date with current dependencies!
Going to run database updates for myWikiName-en_
Depending on the size of your database this may take a while!
```

Please someone tell me what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `SERVER_NAME=my.domain.org` before running `php update.php`. The  script might be looking for `$_SERVER` which, as you are running from the command line, is not available.

Comment: I have tried a myriad of things. e.g. in my LocalSettings.php `if(!defined('HTTP_HOST')) define('HTTP_HOST','web01-my.test.mySite.org');` This does not work. It still does not recognise a HTTP_HOST. Your approach does not seem to work either. Well, it always works. As soon as i run the `update.php` it updates my english site as shown above.

Comment: If you read you error message again, it says “Undefined _index_”, not “Undefined variable”, so defining `HTTP_HOST` will not help. It's looking for (probably) `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`. Look at line 176 in your LocalSettings.php, and you'll know for sure

Answer (score 1):

When you take a look at /maintenance/update.php, you'll see that it is an extension to /maintenance/Maintenance.php, where various option parameters have been defined.

I had success using the conf option which tells the Maintenance.php script (and the update.php script, too) about the location of the LocalSettings.php file to be used:

```
$ php update.php --conf /var/www/<myWebfolder>/da/LocalSettings.php
$ php update.php --conf /var/www/<myWebfolder>/de/LocalSettings.php
$ php update.php --conf /var/www/<myWebfolder>/en/LocalSettings.php
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this appears to be to echo the language and pipe to the command. E.g.

```
for lang in en de es; do
    echo $lang | php update.php || read x
done
```

(the above will run the updater for the languages 'en', 'de', and 'es', and will stop and wait for input from command line if one of them fails)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to manually set the `$wgDBprefix` to first de_ then es_ and finally en_ for my three languages. This way i could run the Update.php script once for every wiki-family-member.

Thank you for the help @leo